# How to build Crypto++ library on Linux with MinGW?

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, cross-compiling, crypto++

im trying to port a c++ project from visual studio 2013 to netbeans on ubuntu. The target is a windows executable, so far im able to compile windows exe files from netbeans using mingw as compiler.

The project needs the Crypto++ library and i only have the .lib version for visual studio. To include the library in netbeans i first need to build the Crypto++ library in the .a format.

Its not clear to me how should i do that.
Ive found informations on how to build the library for linux with mingw but not for cross compilation with mingw. The provided GNUmakefile does not work.
Should i set up a vm with windows and mingw and compile the library that way? Or maybe use the qmake "hack" as suggested here http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28809-Compiling-amp-using-Crypto-with-mingw-version-of-Qt ? The last good Crypto++ version suggested there is quite old. This is confusing, porting the whole project is easier than having the required library.
Im open to any suggestion.

tldr: how to build libcryptopp.a on linux for the cross compilation of a windows exe project

edit:
for example if i cross compile something there are windows libraries in the /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ folder like libuser32.a. i need to make the equivalend libcryptopp.a.. sorry if is a bit unclear.
if i simply build using the steps in answer (and in the wiki) i end up with a libcryptopp.a file but i suspect is linux-only, cause if i link that library in netbeans in the .exe file im cross compiling i end up with undefined references to cryptopp stuff everywere. the paths are correct, i suspect the library needs to be replaced with the equivalent libcryptopp.a compatible with crosscompiling.

edit2: im trying to follow the answer down here, now im stuck here. after this command to build cryptopp.

```
    make CXX=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc INCLUDES="-I /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include" LIBS="-L /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib" CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x"
```

and many variations of it i always end up with this error

trap.h:26:25: fatal error: Windows.h: No such file or directory
 #    include

which makes me think its using the right compiler to make a .a lib file for cross compiling the windows .exe with the lib.
however i dont understand whats going on now with the missing header..:(

Also if i try to link the lib file (used with visual studio) i get a lot of linking errors, undefined reference to cryptopp stuff.

ill offer a symbolic beer (a couple of $ of Bitcoins) if someone finds out how to do it.

Comment: *"The provided GNUmakefile does not work..."* - if you have a specific problem, then you should state what it is. This does not tell us anything useful. Did you use `-a` with `unzip`?

Comment: yes i did use -a with unzip.

Comment: Go to the [Crypto++ User List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cryptopp-users) and raise the question. We'll take this issue up there. Stack Overflow does not lend itself to the communication we need. As far as I know, this sort of thing has never been discussed. State you are trying to cross-compile. Tell us how you got into the configurations (like what packages you installed). Tell us exactly how you build. Provide a sample invocation on the compiler (one source file, like `cryptlib.cpp`).

Comment: i made it somehow, i replaced gcc with g++ in the make string i posted in the edit 2 in the op. it throws some linking errors about winsock2 but the library is actually built and seems to work. too bad i found out that a lot of stuff of the project i was going to port to netbeans is not compatible between compilers and its probably a big pain in the ass to fix. Thanks for the help jww :)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by http://wiki.amule.org/wiki/Cross-compilation_for_windows_with_mingw:

```sh
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp
cd cryptopp
export TARGET=i686-w64-mingw32
CXX=$TARGET-g++ RANLIB=$TARGET-ranlib AR=$TARGET-ar LDLIBS=-lws2_32 make -f GNUmakefile
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've found informations on how to build the library for linux with mingw but not for cross compilation with mingw.

Its relatively easy...

1. Get Crypto++ ZIP into MinGW.
2. Unpack Crypto++ ZIP.
3. Change directories.
4. Build the library.
5. Verify ***`All tests passed`***.

(1) and (2) can be tricky because Cygwin and MinGW are missing a lot of tools. So `curl https://www.cryptopp.com/cryptopp563.zip -o cryptopp563.zip` may not work.

For (2), I seem to recall ZIP is missing, so `unzip -aoq cryptopp563.zip -d cryptopp-5.6.3` may not work.

At step (4), just perform `make static dynamic test` and be sure it finished with ***`All tests passed`***.

I do a lot of testing with Cygwin and MinGW. I have a script that copies Crypto++ into the environments from my Desktop. I have not been able to figure out a way to automate it. A recent question on automating it was closed, so no one can supply an answer (see [How to automate software testing for Cygwin and MinGW](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/299614)).

Comment: im trying to do this on latest ubuntu, with mingw32 and 64 installed, of course curl and unzip work, and make static dynamic test ends with All tests passed. However i suspect that by doing this im building the .a library for linux and it will not work if i link that lib to a .exe file for windows. If i add the library to my .exe windows project in netbeans it doesnt work. running "i686-w64-mingw32-g++ make static dynamic test" or i686-w64-mingw32-gcc gets errors like make: no such file static:no such file dynamic: no such file..how can i build a .a cryptopp library to link to the .exe file?

Comment: tldr: your steps are correct but doing those on a ubuntu box with mingw produces a .a library file only for linux (correct me if im wrong). How to produce a .a library that works with the .exe file im going to cross compile? Do i need to set up a VM with windows, cygwin/mingw and build just the library there? Thanks jww

Comment: im trying to cross compile a .exe windows file from ubuntu using gcc/g++/mingw and that toolchain.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused (but its due to my ignorance)... I don't use MinGW on Ubuntu, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm going to have to step out.

Comment: im confused too :) i could try doing that from a windows box with mingw if everything else fails. Thanks.

Comment: "How to automate software testing" link 404