# Error compiling my CryptoPP Project with mingw on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, mingw, crypto++

I'm new to c++ and i'm trying to use CryptoPP library for AES Encryption.
I use Cmake and I import the library using this lines :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(CryptoPP_Example_AES)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(CryptoPP_Example_AES main.cpp)
find_library(CryptoPP libcryptopp.a REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(CryptoPP_Example_AES ${CryptoPP})
```

For information I've installed libcrypto++6 libcrypto++-dev libcrypto++dbg.

Like this everything works fine and my project is compiled.

The problem is when I try to compile it using `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++)`
MinGW do not find the library anymore.

Here's my main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH );
    memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

    //
    // String and Sink setup
    //
    std::string plaintext = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide...";
    std::string ciphertext;
    std::string decryptedtext;

    //
    // Dump Plain Text
    //
    std::cout << "Plain Text (" << plaintext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << plaintext;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //
    // Create Cipher Text
    //
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
    stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    //
    // Dump Cipher Text
    //
    std::cout << "Cipher Text (" << ciphertext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;

    for(char i : ciphertext) {

        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte >(i)) << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    //
    // Decrypt
    //
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
    stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ciphertext.c_str() ), ciphertext.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    //
    // Dump Decrypted Text
    //
    std::cout << "Decrypted Text: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << decryptedtext;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, when I use `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++)` my IDE tell me there is no cryptopp Header files, as you can see on the screen :
[CLion IDE telling me there is no headers files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANAlR.png)

Can someone help me on this ? I searched a long time on the web but doesn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you installed the mingw versions of the cryptopp libraries? The Linux ones won't work

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles thanks for the reply, didn't know Linux one's won't work.
So I followed this topic : [how-to-build-crypto-library-on-linux-with-mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087932/how-to-build-crypto-library-on-linux-with-mingw)
And add to my CMakeList.txt to :
`find_library(CryptoPP "/usr/lib/cryptopp/libcryptopp.a" REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++)
target_link_libraries(CryptoPP_Example_AES ${CryptoPP})'

It is not working.
What am I doing wrong ? How can I install the mingw version so ?

Comment: Is `"/usr/lib/cryptopp/libcryptopp.a"` where you've installed your mingw version of cryptopp?

Comment: Yep, But I make a mistake writing the path.
When Building and installing Cryptopp with x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++, I decided to put the installed files to /usr/lib/cryptopp.
So in "usr/lib/cryptopp/" I got 3 directories :
- /bin (with cryptest.exe and libcryptopp.a)
- /includes/cryptopp/ (with all the headers file)
- /share (with datatest)

When writing the path I made a mistake but it is ok in my code

I have a new error now, I linked the include directory for the headers files and my libcryptopp.a and now got a new error : `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptopp.so` : file not recognized

Comment: I really not telling Cmake to search for my .so file. Really don't understand why link something is as difficult ^^

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments but now, with this lines :
`set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++)
 target_include_directories(CryptoPP_Example_AES PUBLIC 
 /usr/lib/cryptopp/include/)
 target_link_libraries(CryptoPP_Example_AES /usr/lib/cryptopp/libcryptopp.a)` 

It seems mingw find everything I need, but now I got a lots of undefined reference in main main.cpp.